Android management API how to stop deleting system application after enrollment
When I enroll a device using the Android Management API, it automatically removes all the default applications like the gallery, clock, etc., when the phone starts. I don't want that; I want to keep those system apps. How can I do this?
I have tried adding the "installAppDisabled" and "playStoreMode" keys in my policy, but it didn't work. I also tried adding the package name in the application object, but I don't know the package names of the applications.

To enable the system applications, you would need to customize the enrollment token returned from enterprises.enrollmentTokens.create and add this to the qrCode object:
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED"  :  true

You may refer to this documentation.
